# How to verify that after required failed attempt user account is blocked in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have username and password in my website, the expected condition is that after 5 attempts of wrong username/password combination, user's account is locked for half an hour..
In my test case I want to file 5 wrong combination and want to read the error message and in the 6th attempt, fill right username/password combination but user's account should be blocked.

In selenium, using Java.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Copy/paste java code here, or.. ?

Comment: Actually my code is not working, so hence I am raising a query, however  I can elaborate my scenario here-    So I have a website like facebook, where in I have username/password fields.. The username gets blocked if you try 5 attempts of wrong username/password combination in the login field, I want to test this functionality. I hope I am making sense now

Comment: Provide an faulty code, so we can help out. This doesn't seem like a big problem. Do in a loop 5 times wrong input, or input 5 times wrong input data click on it, and afterwards find error element (label, or whatever) with certain text, like "Your verification is unsuccessful" and Assert it. That is it.

Comment: Something like this:
1. navigate to the login form. 2. in loop with count 5, add wrong data, and assert displayed message 3. add new try (outside the loop), and assert for the specific message ("your account has been locked for ...")

Comment: Actually there is no separate error message for the locked account, so even if my account is locked I will still get username/password doesn't match, so I wanted to have other way with which I can verify if the account is locked, like 401, unauthorized error.

Comment: If there is no specific message that the account is blocked after 5 tries, only way to verify is to check the database or the service providing login validation.

Comment: when you say check database, what exactly you want me to check?